# Blank white page with php-fpm and httpd on CentOS Stream release 8

Tags: php, apache, centos8

I've installed php, php-fpm and httpd on a **CentOS Stream release 8** server. PHP works fine from command line. php-fpm and httpd are started and running.

I am getting a blank white page when attempting to access this (or any) script:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I'm not showing any errors in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (configured log for the given virtualhost)

There are a few notices in `/var/log/php-fpm/error_log`:

```
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:19] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:19] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:19] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 40153
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:19] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:19] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:54] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:54] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:54] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 40215
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:54] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[06-Feb-2021 22:53:54] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

I haven't touched anything in `/etc/php-fpm.conf`.

`/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` was edited to change the following, per [this tutorial][1]:

```
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
 
user = apache
group = apache
 
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
listen.owner = apache
listen.group = apache
listen.mode = 0660
pm = dynamic
```

`audit2allow < /var/log/audit/audit.log` produces the following:

```
#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t admin_home_t:file getattr;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t kernel_t:system module_request;

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow httpd_t self:process execmem;

#============= local_login_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow local_login_t tmpfs_t:filesystem getattr;

#============= mysqld_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow mysqld_t kernel_t:system module_request;

#============= named_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow named_t kernel_t:system module_request;

#============= rhsmcertd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow rhsmcertd_t kernel_t:system module_request;
```

Here's output from `getsebool -a | grep -i http`

```
httpd_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_check_spam --> off
httpd_can_connect_ftp --> off
httpd_can_connect_ldap --> off
httpd_can_connect_mythtv --> off
httpd_can_connect_zabbix --> off
httpd_can_network_connect --> on
httpd_can_network_connect_cobbler --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
httpd_can_network_memcache --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> on
httpd_dbus_avahi --> off
httpd_dbus_sssd --> off
httpd_dontaudit_search_dirs --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> off
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_graceful_shutdown --> off
httpd_manage_ipa --> off
httpd_mod_auth_ntlm_winbind --> off
httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_run_ipa --> off
httpd_run_preupgrade --> off
httpd_run_stickshift --> off
httpd_serve_cobbler_files --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_tmp_exec --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> off
httpd_unified --> off
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_fusefs --> off
httpd_use_gpg --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
httpd_use_opencryptoki --> off
httpd_use_openstack --> off
httpd_use_sasl --> off
httpd_verify_dns --> off
mysql_connect_http --> off
named_tcp_bind_http_port --> off
prosody_bind_http_port --> off
```

I tried setting

```
setsebool -P httpd_execmem 1
```

and restarted auditd, but still see the same output in audit2allow.

I've also tried setting

```
 setenforce 0
```

to no avail.

I'm at a loss and I should note that this is the first php-fpm setup I've attempted, so it's likely I am missing something really obvious.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Check `audit2allow < /var/log/audit/audit.log`. Note - there will probably be unrelated denials in there. You can possibly `tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow` while causing the php-fpm error to occur.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski added output from audit2allow in my post just now

Comment: Temporarily set SELinux into permissive mode `sudo setenforce 0` load your page in apache, which should work. Get only the last `denied` line from audit.log and put that into audit2allow so it shows exactly which httpd_ denials are relevant. I haven't dealt with this in php-fpm before so I don't know which bool would work. `audit2allo2 -M` can create a new selinux module allowing the things you need.

Comment: Sorry for not being of much help with your specific problem, but just wanted to let you know that CentOS 8 is [expected to be EOL at/after December 31, 2021](https://www.centos.org/download/). Not sure if this will affect your longer-term usage plans.

Comment: issued setenforce 0, still get the blank white page.  pulling my hair out haha.